# Function template overload resolution using const references

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I am trying to understand the overload resolution rules in the following case:

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T& x) { 
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; //-
}

template<typename T>
void f(T& x) { // <> Überladung Variante 2
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; //-
}

int main()
{
    int e1 = 0;
    f(e1);

    const int e2 = 0;
    f(e2); 
}
```

The output is:

```
void f(T &) [T = int]
void f(const T &) [T = int]
```

As I understand in the first call to `f(e1)` leads to the viable functions

```
void f(const int&)
void f(int&)
```

from which the first one is chosen because the const-qualification hasn't  to be removed.

The second call to `f(e2)` leads to the type deductions / viable functions

```
void f(const int&); // T -> int from first template overload 
void f(const int&); // T -> const int from second overload
```

and the output shows that the first overload is choosen.

But why?

Comment: Because when two candidates are equally good in overload resolution, certain tie breakers are applied: nontemplates win vs templates, ..., and more specific templates win against less specific (independent of the actual argument). You want to read into "partial ordering" of function templates.

Comment: And as you read more of the rules you will notice all sorts of pedantry violations. For instance I should have said "non-template functions win against template specializations". Templates are not candidates in overload resolution, but specializations of them. But in the tie, the templates from which the specializations were derived will be attempted to be ordered.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb From an intuitive point of view, isn't this rule designed so that `const`-ness can be distinguished when passed by reference (which doesn't really make sense when passing by value)? And of course CV makes the overload more specialized, i.e. less disordered, so it goes up as a candidate in the partial ordering list.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to "partial ordering". I digged into http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template  and found that adding qualifiers to the template type T (e.g. const T& or T*) renders that template overload as more specialized. So in this case the f(const T&) is selected.

Answer (score 4):

When performing type deduction with references, the `const`-ness (more specifically CV-ness) is not removed. So in your case the compiler has 2 overloads to choose from:

```
void f(const T &)
void f(T &)
```

The compiler then performs "pattern matching" when choosing the overload for your `const int e2 = 0;` argument. The first `const` overload is a better match (more specialized), as the second one would require deducing `T` as `const int`, which adds something (i.e. `const`-ness).

The rules for template type deductions are not super straightforward, so if you want to learn all nitty-gritty details about templates, I highly recommend the book

[C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis.

It's pre C++11, but nevertheless it tells you **everything** you can think of.

PS: you must make a differentiation between *instantiation* and *template type deduction*. The type deduction happens first, then an instantiation follows. So in your case you don't have 2 ambiguous instantiations as you may have thought initially.

Comment: That makes sense, but "*[...]as the second one would require deducing `T` as `const int` [..]*", why does this bring the compiler to choose the first one? Why does this should be a disadvantage? Can you add something from standard? Or explain it?

Comment: The compiler tries to minimize adding CV when possible. It makes some sense if you think about, everything in nature tries to minimize "action". So the C++ designers thought about this in the same way. Unfortunately I don't have the standard handy, maybe someone can add a quote and make this a better answer. I read this in the book I've linked though. At worst it can be an ambiguity (definitely the second `T&` cannot be a better choice), but choosing this rule for type deduction allows the differentiation between `const` vs non-`const` for references, which is useful.

Comment: Ok, then I may summarize: the type decution leds to two identical overloads, and the deduction T -> const int is dicarded then.

Comment: Yeah, As I've said this makes sense, of course. But I cannot accept "*everything in nature tries to minimize 'action'.*", because if that were the case, then there would be many "rules" in C++ disagree with that.

Comment: @BiagioFesta Again, many rules in C++ are complicated. Overload resolution is probably the most complicated of all, if you look at the standard there are tons of exceptions etc. In this case my belief is that allowing this rule allows for `const` vs non-`const` differentiation for objects passed by reference. BTW, if you pass by value, then `const` is discarded, you copy anyway, so you'll get an ambiguity. Passing by reference should allow you to distinguish CV, so the standard allows it. That's the intuitive explanation I have about it. In the standard, you'll probably find the dry rule.

Comment: @wimalopaan Yes, the `const T&` is a better match for `const int`, so when ordering the candidates, the `const T&` is chosen. See also @Johannes Schaub - litb's comment.

Comment: Let me try to summarize even further: the call `f(e1)` leds to two possible overloads after typ deduction: `f(const int&)` and `f(int&)`. From those the latter gets selected by the qualification conversion rule. But the call to `f(e2)` leds to two (impossible) overloads `f(const int&)`. Here the partial ordering comes in and selects the more specialized version `f(const T&)`. Looks resonable to me but can be much more complicated.

Comment: @wimalopaan Yes, basically the more specialized match is being selected. Same as when you have `f(T)` and `f(T*)` and passing a pointer. The second one is selected, it is more specialized.

Comment: Yes, I wanted only to clarify the distinction between partial ordering and overload resolution ...

Comment: @wimalopaan I think the partial ordering is a part of overload resolution. It is performed first, then a candidate set is being built. The less specialized functions are being eliminated from the set.